# Best practices for naming java maven projects and artifact-producing maven projects

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi-module maven project that looks like this;

```
upsilon-node (packaging: pom)
|--- upsilon-jar (contains the actual source code - .java files, produces a .jar)
|--- upsilon-node-rpm-fedora (produces a Fedora RPM, from the upsilon-jar's .jar)
|--- upsilon-node-rpm-debian (products a Debian DEB, from the upsilon-jar's .jar)
|--- upsilon-node-nsis (produces a .exe installer, from the upsilon-jar's .jar)
|--- (various other packages)
```

I have two questions:

1) To me, the .java source code should logically go in the parent upsilon-node project, but when the packaing is set to .jar, it seems I cannot have submodules - submodules are only possible from packaging:pom projects.

2) Does this look sane, am I following best practice here? I read somewhere that 1 project should produce exactly 1 artifact.

Look forward to hearing your thoughts, thanks!

---

Note, project is on GitHub: https://github.com/upsilonproject/upsilon/tree/master/upsilon-node

Anything you spot that looks like I'm now following best practice, very keen to hear it.

Comment: Why are you defining all the time the `finalname`? It's only for the target folder for nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

In Maven the best practice and of course supported by Maven itself (which means a requirement) is that the parent `upsilon-node` in your case should not contain any code (maven forces you to define packging `pom`). Usually you define plugins (their appropriate version etc.), dependencies for all of your modules, configurations (encoding etc.).

For example you defined the encoding in the parent:

```xml
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

If you did that you don't need to repeat that in your child modules, cause it will be inherited to the childs.

Apart from that within your build you did not defined any dependencies between the modules which seemed to be necessary. This can result in unpredictable build results. For example you have module which generates a tgz but you can't be sure that the used artifacts have been built before. So define dependencies between the module to let maven reactor define the order of the execution.

So furthermore to the `rule` one pom one artifact can be said that's more or less true, cause you are already using a module which "violates" the rule (node-tgz) which simply can create multiple artifacts.